# Adding a condition to a long string of object relations in Laravel / Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, api, eloquent

Essentially I am just trying to add a where condition to this request where I get a "Phase" with a bunch of its children (i sudo'd it up a bit) :

```
public function show($projectId, $phaseId)
{
    return Phase::with('headers.subheaders.lines.values')->findOrFail($phase);
}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
public function show($projectId, $phaseId)
{
    return Phase::with('headers.subheaders.lines.projectValues')
        ->where('headers.subheaders.lines.projectValues.project_id', '=' , $projectId)
        ->findOrFail($phaseId);
}
```

I've tried various variations of this :

```
return Phase::with(['headers.subheaders.lines.projectValues' => function ($query) use ($projectId) {
    $query->where('project_id', $projectId);
}])->findOrFail($phaseId);
```

But I can't find the magical combination of syntax to get this working properly.  I normally get the error that project_id is not an attribute of phase for the last example... I've tried giving it the full path twice but it doesn't seem to like it... Maybe I'm just being dumb and theres a simple solution...

**Edit :**

Some of the relationships:

```
class Line extends Model
{
   // Other stuff
    public function projectValues()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProjectValues::class, 'question_id');
    }
}


class QuestionValue extends Model
{
    // Other stuff

    public function project()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
    }

    public function line()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Line::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ben, please add the relationship between the Phase model and the Project.

Comment: There is no relationship with the Phase and the Project, just the values at the end of the tree

Comment: A Line has many ProjectValues but I would like just the ProjectValues in the Phase that correspond to my variable (the current project) @AliAli

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a chain of `whereHas`:

```
 return Phase::with('headers.subheaders.lines.projectValues')
            ->whereHas('headers',function ($query)use($project_id){
                $query->whereHas('subheaders',function ($query2)use($project_id){
                    $query2->whereHas('lines',function ($query3)use($project_id){
                        $query3->whereHas('projectValues',function ($query4)use($project_id){
                            $query4->where('project_id','=',$project_id);
                        });
                    });
                });
            })
            ->findOrFail($phaseId);
```

Comment: The thing is if there is no questionValue I still want the Line... does that work in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by questionValue ?

Comment: The most granular object there, where we check the project_id, will I still get a Line that has 0 ProjectValues in its relation? The way "whereHas()" is worded it sounds like I won't...